# jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over number (400)

Tags: shell, scripting

I wrote a shell script using curl to get the APIKEY and pass it through the curl dynamic variable in the key, but i am getting the error

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over number (400)
```

The error is thrown by:

```sh
#/bin/bash

echo " Please enter the API Key";
apikey=$(curl -i --silent -u useranme:passwd https://api.ABC.net/auth -k | grep -i X-Api-Key |cut -d\  -f 2);
echo $apikey;

echo " Please enter the VAC value to patch";
read DOW;

curl -s https://api.ABC.net/vac/api/v1/search/servers\?status\="/(i).*active.*/"\&updates_window\=$DOW-America_Los_Angeles\&updates_window_disable\=false\&updates_window_skip_next\=false\&updates_last_status="completed_failed" -H "Authorization: $apikey" -k | grep -e fqdn;
```

While executing the script, the `$apikey` variable is not passed and curl does not execute.

Comment: Are you sure this part of the script is throwing the error? I can't see `jq` in the script, but it is mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Also, jq expects a JSON content. Wherever you are using it (probably like `some_program_with_an_output | jq `) it is getting a number instead of a JSON document.

Comment: Sorry I have given wrong Curl command but that curl also not passing the dynamic input of API key..

Here the Jq curl command error throwing:

jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over number (400)
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 8

curl -s https://example.net/vac/api/v1/search/servers\?status\="/(?i).*active.*/"\&updates_window\=$DOW-America_Los_Angeles\&updates_window_disable\=false\&updates_window_skip_next\=false -H "Authorization: $apikey" -k | jq "group_by( .updates_last_status ) | map( { LastStatus: .[0].updates_last_status, Count: length } ) | .[]";